# Sorting some code and i need to shorten it

Tags: sorting, python-3.x

```
  fd = open('Class1.txt')
  lines = [line.strip() for line in fd]
  s = {}
  for line in lines:
    splitted = [i for i in line.split(',')]
    key = splitted[0]
    s[key] = [int(n) for n in splitted[1:]]
  def average():
          avg_mark = lambda name:sum(s[name])/len(s[name])
          for i in sorted(s.keys(),key=avg_mark,reverse=True):
              print (i,avg_mark(i),"\n")
          average()
          average()
  average()
```

Right so i've changed the code so then it just does the average but when i run it it doesn't stop can anyone help me.
thanks

I need help shortening this piece of code because it is too long. I need to do this for three other classes as well and don't want it to be lines of code and was just wandering if it could be shortened.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't use SO to cheat on your GCSEs. You should be submitting **your own work**, not getting the internet to rewrite it.

Comment: Why would you want it shortened?

Comment: Repeating a request for input by recursively calling the function is bad design. See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/953482)

Comment: to make it look more professional

Comment: Since this almost certainly about your [GCSE programming problem](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2gawvg/gcse_computing_programming_tasks_14_16_year_olds/), please do read [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think you're after:

```
import csv

with open('Class1.txt') as fd:
    s = {row[0]:[int(n) for n in row[1:]] for row in csv.reader(fd, delimiter=',')}

def average():
    avg_mark = lambda name : sum(s[name])/len(s[name])
    for name in sorted(s, key=avg_mark, reverse=True):
        print(name, avg_mark(name))  # newline prints automatically
```

Of course, in reality, because of the call to `average` within `average`, you're going to run into `maxrecursiondepth` issues. So if you really want code to do that, you may as well just do this:

```
def f(): f()
```